# Search and Return Matched Substrings from Array Values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
0 => dsadjdasActionsdadas | 123 4Dramdsadsa
1 => dsakjdsa Crime dasdsadas Sci-Fci
2 => dasjhdashkAdventuredsadsasa
```

I want to trim everything except "Action", "Dram", "Crime", "Sci-Fci", "Adventure" and " | " to change the array's key values to something like this. It has to be case sensitive.

```
0 => Action | Dram
1 => Crime | Sci-Fci
2 => Adventure
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. As of now, simple string functions (e.g. `substr()` combined with `strpos()`) would do. If it's getting more complicated, you might need a regex - but be more precise on what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with `preg_match_all`, `array_map` and `implode` functions:

```
$arr = [
    0 => 'dsadjdasActionsdadas | 123 4Dramdsadsa',
    1 => 'dsakjdsa Crime dasdsadas |Sci-Fci',
    2 => 'dasjhdashkAdventuredsadsasa'
];

$result = array_map(function($v){
    preg_match_all("/(Action|Dram|Crime|Sci-Fci|Adventure|\|)+?/", $v, $matches);
    return implode(' ',$matches[0]);
}, $arr);


var_dump($result);
// the output:
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Action | Dram' (length=13)
  1 => string 'Crime | Sci-Fci' (length=15)
  2 => string 'Adventure' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```
$array = array("dsadjdasActionsdadas | 123 4Dramdsadsa", "dsakjdsa Crime | dasdsadas Sci-Fci", "dasjhdashkAdventuredsadsasa");
print_r($array);
$clean_array = array_map('cleanGenre', $array);
print_r($clean_array);

function cleanGenre($text)
{
    $genres = array('Action', 'Adventure', 'Crime', 'Dram', 'Sci-Fci');
    $parts = explode("|", $text);
    $result = array();
    foreach($parts as $part)
        foreach($genres as $genre)
            if (preg_match("/". $genre. "/i", $part))
                $result[] = $genre;
    return (implode(' | ', $result));
}
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dsadjdasActionsdadas | 123 4Dramdsadsa
    [1] => dsakjdsa Crime | dasdsadas Sci-Fci
    [2] => dasjhdashkAdventuredsadsasa
)
Array
(
    [0] => Action | Dram
    [1] => Crime | Sci-Fci
    [2] => Adventure
)
```

Note that I've inserted a '|' symbol in $array[1]

This is my very first post!